# Creating trigger function in Postgres

Tags: 7, database

I was developing my own customized module in Drupal 7. Is there any way I can create at run-time a trigger function in PostgresSQL? A sample scenario is when after successfully deleting a record in a particular table.

Comment: Drupal doesn't offer any helper function for creating database triggers. What you use for that is plain PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`db_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x) function for that:

> Executes an arbitrary query string against the active database.

e.g.

```
db_query('postgres-specific SQL here');
```

Note: if the DBMS you're connected to at any point *isn't* pg, and it doesn't understand the statement you're executing, that code will throw an exception. Probably best to catch that and handle if your module needs to be portable.